Laplacian of Gaussian(LoG) blob detector c++
I'm writing a blob detector based on LoG. I am using the openCV library. The task is to detect light circles on a dark background. Picture type CV_8UC1
Original picture (noisy on purpose)

https://i.sstatic.net/eBglu.png
It all started with the fact that for some reason the minimum response was given by a blob with a larger radius than the desired circle itself. I got to the point where the error lies in matching the sizes of the cv::GaussianBlur and cv::Laplacian kernels.
For example, the first picture is with all the found blobs (sorted to remove false positives), the second picture is the abandoned blobs with minimal response. To find blobs of different sizes, I use the cv::pyrDown scale pyramid and LoG sigma^2 response normalization.

https://i.sstatic.net/sjxDl.jpg

https://i.sstatic.net/drot2.jpg
From the documentation I didn’t understand what size should be specified in the parameters to the functions - the size of the wing or the actual size of the core. For example, if I specify ksize = 5 in the parameters. Will the size of the Gaussian kernel be equal to 5? And the size of the Laplace kernel will be equal to 11 - according to the formula 2*n + 1?
I tried to find the answer by obtaining nuclei. That is, I used the functions cv::getGaussianKernel and cv::getDerivKernels. But for some reason, the result of applying cv::Laplacian to the resulting Gaussian kernel gives a slightly different result. Namely, in the case of using cv::GaussianBlur and cv::Laplacian, I received the minimum response at the point [155, 710] with the value -144004136960.000000, and in the case of using cv::getGaussianKernel and cv:: The Laplacian minimum response I received was at point [155, 710] with the value -9097119744.000000. I used the same core sizes. I multiplied the kernel obtained by cv::getGaussianKernel by the transposed kernel, since the cv::getGaussianKernel function gives a one-dimensional kernel.
I don't understand the reasons for this behavior.
The first image is obtained using the classical method, while the second is obtained by applying cv::Laplacian to the Gaussian kernel obtained from cv::getGaussianKernel.

https://i.sstatic.net/KZWGi.png

https://i.sstatic.net/oIJ95.png
This is how LoG looks when finding the Gaussian kernel using cv::getGaussianKernel.

https://i.sstatic.net/SlIFb.png
Next I tried to get the Laplace kernel. For this I used
 cv::getDerivKernels(sobelKernelX, sobelKernelY, 2, 2, kernelsizes);
 cv::Mat sobelKernel = sobelKernelX * sobelKernelX.t() + sobelKernelY * sobelKernelY.t();

But I got a very bad and incorrect result.

https://i.sstatic.net/plXBP.png
This is how LoG looked.

https://i.sstatic.net/EmL4x.png
 //values used
 double sigmakz = 3.2;
 int kernelsizes = static_cast<int>(6*sigmakz);
 
 //classic version
 image.convertTo(temprrrr_reverse, CV_32F);
 cv::GaussianBlur(temprrrr_reverse, tryinguff, cv::Size(kernelsizes, kernelsizes), sigmakz);
 cv::Laplacian(tryinguff, outtt, CV_32F, kernelsizes);

 //option to obtain a Gaussian kernel
 cv::Mat gausKernel = cv::getGaussianKernel(kernelsizes, sigmakz, CV_32F);
 cv::Mat temprrrr = gausKernel * gausKernel.t();
 cv::Mat smth;
 cv::Laplacian(temprrrr, smth, CV_32F, kernelsizes);
 cv::Mat hrrr;
 cv::filter2D(image, hrrr, CV_32F, smth);

 //option to obtain the kernel of the second derivative
 cv::Mat sobelKernelX;
 cv::Mat sobelKernelY;
 cv::getDerivKernels(sobelKernelX, sobelKernelY, 2, 2, kernelsizes);

 cv::Mat sobelKernel = sobelKernelX * sobelKernelX.t() + sobelKernelY * sobelKernelY.t();

 cv::Mat tryinguff;
 //temprr = gausKernel * gausKernel.t();
 cv::filter2D(temprrrr, tryinguff, CV_32F, sobelKernel);

 cv::Mat outtt;
 cv::filter2D(image, outtt, CV_32F, tryinguff);

The main question is how to correctly coordinate the sizes of cores from a technical point of view? What values should I specify in the ksize parameters for Laplacian and Gaussian?

pictures please

I can't because i haven't reached 10 reputation points(

I managed to add images))

those are screenshots, even of the "original picture". not ideal. -- the site does allow you to upload images, but it might not embed them, but only place a link.

I added links to photos if I understand you correctly
